# I want to know if this is possible while differentiating

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

The question is $\Rightarrow $ ${\sqrt {1-x^2}}+{\sqrt {1-y^2}} =a (x-y)$. Show that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{\sqrt {1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$

Below I've mentioned how i approached it.

$${\sqrt {1-x^2}}+{\sqrt {1-y^2}} =a (x-y) \Rightarrow (1)$$
$$let; 1-x^2=u^2, 1-y^2=v^2$$
$$u+v=a ({\sqrt {1-u^2}}-{\sqrt{1-v^2}})$$
differentiating with respect to v

$$\frac{du}{dv}=\left(\frac{\sqrt {1-u^2}}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)\left(\frac {av-{\sqrt {1-v^2}}} {au+{\sqrt{1-u^2}}}\right)$$
$${when;u\to y},{v\to x} \Rightarrow \alpha$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{\sqrt {1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\left(\frac {ax-{\sqrt {1-x^2}}} {ay+{\sqrt{1-y^2}}}\right)$$

From (1) the things in second brackets cancel of,
$$Finally,\\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{\sqrt {1-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

The only reason for using step  $α$ is because when done the things in the brackets cancel off.

Since that is wrong if there is any other method (than the one where you substitute sinα for x and sinβ for y and so on...) let me know.

Also can anyone explain to me when and where i can use step α and why i cant use it wherever i want to.

Comment: Please use [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out your image. Many users cannot view images and they are also not searchable on the site. By typing it out, more people will be able to see it and help you

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is.. Are you trying to find the derivative of y with respect to x? In that case, this answer is most certainly wrong.

Comment: It's unclear when you write u$\to$y and v$\to$x. How did you change u an v to x and y?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.Ive editted the question and if anyone can explain why i cant do that.

Answer (score 1):

The method where you substitute sinα & sinβ for x and y.Maybe It'll be helpfull for someone else.

$${\sqrt {1-x^2}}+{\sqrt {1-y^2}} =a (x-y)
\\ let;x=\sin α, y=\sin β\\then; α=\arcsin x ,  β=\arcsin y$$
Substitute for $x$ & $y$
$${\sqrt {1- (\sin α)^2}}+{\sqrt {1- (\sinβ)^2}} =a (\sinα-\sinβ)
\\ \cosα+\cosβ=a (\sinα -\sinβ)
\\ 2\cos\left(\frac {α+β}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {α-β}{2}\right)=a \biggl(2\cos\left(\frac {α+β}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac {α-β}{2}\right)\biggr)
\\ \frac {1}{a} = \tan\left(\frac {α-β}{2}\right)
\\ 2\arctan \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)= α-β$$
Substitute for α & β

$$2\arctan \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=\arcsin x - \arcsin y $$

By Differentiating with respect to x
$$0= \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}\right)-\frac {dy}{dx}\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-y^2}}\right)
\\ \frac {dy}{dx}=\left(\frac {\sqrt {1-y^2}}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}\right) $$
$\Bbb Note: $ 
$2\arctan \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$ is a constant so when differentiated with respect to x it equals to zero

$ \frac {d}{dx}  2\arctan \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=0$

Comment: Let me know if there are any other methods